# Custom activation with parameter

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer, activation-function

I'm trying to create an activation function in Keras that can take in a parameter `beta` like so:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
from keras.layers import Activation

class Swish(Activation):

    def __init__(self, activation, beta, **kwargs):
        super(Swish, self).__init__(activation, **kwargs)
        self.__name__ = 'swish'
        self.beta = beta


def swish(x):
    return (K.sigmoid(beta*x) * x)

get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Swish(swish, beta=1.)})
```

It runs fine without the `beta` parameter, but how can I include the parameter in the activation definition? I also want this value to be saved when I do `model.to_json()` like for ELU activation.

---

**Update:** I wrote the following code based on @today's answer:

```
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras import backend as K

class Swish(Layer):
    def __init__(self, beta, **kwargs):
        super(Swish, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.beta = K.cast_to_floatx(beta)
        self.__name__ = 'swish'

    def call(self, inputs):
        return K.sigmoid(self.beta * inputs) * inputs

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'beta': float(self.beta)}
        base_config = super(Swish, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Swish(beta=1.)})
gnn = keras.models.load_model("Model.h5")
arch = gnn.to_json()
with open(directory + 'architecture.json', 'w') as arch_file:
    arch_file.write(arch)
```

However, it does not currently save the `beta` value in the .json file. How can I make it save the value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to save the parameters of activation function when serializing the model, I think it is better to define the activation function as a layer like the [advanced activations which have been defined in Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py). You can do it like this:

```
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras import backend as K

class Swish(Layer):
    def __init__(self, beta, **kwargs):
        super(Swish, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.beta = K.cast_to_floatx(beta)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return K.sigmoid(self.beta * inputs) * inputs

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'beta': float(self.beta)}
        base_config = super(Swish, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Then you can use it the same way you use a Keras layer:

```
# ...
model.add(Swish(beta=0.3))
```

Since `get_config()` method has been implemented in its definition, the parameter `beta` would be saved when using methods like `to_json()` or `save()`.

Comment: This is what I do but the parameter value is not saved in the json file

Comment: @user7867665 Are you sure you have implemented `get_config()` method and include `beta` parameter in it?

Comment: I did it differently, I am testing your implementation now

Comment: it doesn't save the beta value in the .json file, I used exactly your code

Comment: @user7867665 Strange indeed! It works for me. Could you please put your code in a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/) (or any other online note sharing website which gives shareable link) and give the link to me?

Comment: How do I give you the link, is there direct messages?

Comment: @user7867665 Just paste it in the comment here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182785/discussion-between-user7867665-and-today).

Comment: @user7867665 You are using `generator.to_json()` but your model is stored in `gnn`?! Plus, it is not a good idea to edit your question by removing the original question. Add any more info at the end instead. Hence, I rolled back your edit and modified as such.

Comment: It's `gnn.to_json()`, I pasted the wrong thing. Fixed. Problem is still the same. Thanks for the edit

Comment: @user7867665 Run [this code](https://www.pastiebin.com/5bd89a20d1489) on your machine and confirm that you see the `beta` parameter in the printed config. Further, look at how the custom object is passed to `load_model` function.

Comment: It works! So why doesn't it work for my model? Maybe because it was not trained using this definition of swish?

Comment: So it didn't work on my model because it was not trained using this definition of swish. Thanks a lot!